# What are 'Loyalty Points'?

Tags: eve-online

I have been doing some PvE missions outside of the initial training missions and have noticed that in addition to ISK and the occasional item I am now accumulating something called 'Loyalty Points':

[image]

What are Loyalty Points, where can I spend them and what can I spend them on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loyalty Points are a special currency earned from missions. In (I think) any station owned by the corporation for which you did the mission, you can access the LP Store and buy special items with them, such as blueprints, unique ships, ammo, and crystals.

Comment: As an added note, frequently the higher level items will require that you pay with some items AND LP, like a ship or NPC tags or similar.

Comment: The LP store has the same icon as the Loyalty Points above, and can be found in the Station window.

Comment: More added note: All the corporation LP stores are different. They mostly offer rewards related to that corporation activity: mining modules for mining corps, combat related modules for fighting corps, etc... [This website](http://www.ellatha.com/eve/LP_Stores.asp) list a lot (all?) of the LP reward, and could be helpful you you want to choose your main missioning corp based on LP rewards.

Comment: @Lysarion Ah, that's good to know. I only worked for a fighting corp, so I didn't realize the LP stores varied.

Answer (score 1):

Loyalty Points are how corporations repay members for services rendered. One example is given through missioning, as an additional reward for completing them. Other way of getting loyalty points is Faction Warfare, which gives you LP for that factions militia, and Incursions, which give Concord LP.

LP is spent buying items specific to that faction or group. Each race has things they specialize in, and so their faction items will be better (ie. Caldari Navy Ballistic Control System). LP is locked to the corp that you received it for, with the exception of Concord which can be traded to any factions LP. You can check each corps LP store by going to a station owned by that npc corp and checking their Loyalty market.

Some items are generic and can be found in nearly any LP store, such as implants.